# Django: save pdf to server instead of client

Tags: django

I use django-wkhtmltopdf to generate pdf reports. The report then downloads to the clients machine. I would like to to leave a copy of it on the server. How do i go about saving the pdf's directly to the server.

Heres my pdf view:

```
class PDFView(DetailView):
    template = 'pdf_reports/report.html'
    today = datetime.now()
    context = {'today': today.strftime('%d %b %Y')}
    model = Model

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.context['model'] = self.get_object()

        response=PDFTemplateResponse(request=request,
                                     template=self.template,
                                     filename ="report.pdf",


       context=self.context,
                                 show_content_in_browser=False,
                                 cmd_options={'margin-top': 0,
                                              'margin-left': 0,
                                              'margin-right': 0}
                                 )
    return response
```

Comment: I'd imagine you save the response in the same way you do a [fileupload](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads) I havent tried this though..

Answer (score -1):

Try [pdfkit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit), which also uses `wkhtmltopdf`:

```
import pdfkit

pdfkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'out.pdf')
```

To save in a model, try this:

```
import tempfile
import pdfkit

from django.core.files.base import File

# instance is your model

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as fh:
    pdfkit.from_url('http://google.com', fh.name)
    instance.pdf = File(fh)
    instance.save()
```

Comment: Where is `instance` defined?